# JBoss EAP 6.2 on RHEL 6: ./bin/init.d/jboss-as-standalone.sh hangs while calling via SSH

Tags: bash, redhat, rhel6, jboss

I'm using jboss-as-standalone.sh to manage JBoss EAP standalone as a service. I can start/stop the service with "service jboss-as-standalone.sh start/stop" while I'm on a terminal.

But I would like to start JBoss from outside the server via SSH using our Continuous Deployment Infrastructure. Therefore I'm issueing a command like this:

```
ssh root@myserver "service jboss-as-standalone.sh start"
```

The server starts up normally but SSH hangs. It seems it isn't able to close the connection because of the background job forked by this command in the script:

```
daemon --user $JBOSS_USER LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1 JBOSS_PIDFILE=$JBOSS_PIDFILE SERVER_HOME=$SERVER_HOME $JBOSS_SCRIPT -c $JBOSS_CONFIG 2>&1 > $JBOSS_CONSOLE_LOG &
```

Is there any other possibility to start JBoss as a service which works with notty SSH connections as well?

Best regards

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 nohup service jboss-as-standalone.sh start &>/dev/null
```

Check [`man nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) for more information.

Comment: If you would do that, you need to read what &> does.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Must have been tired, sorry.